# Spring Boot jar - META-INF inside BOOT-INF folder

Tags: spring-boot, jar, packaging, meta-inf, runnable-jar

Is there any way to have META-INF folder inside BOOT-INF in spring boot packaging jar?
This might be a trivial question, but not sure how to do it. Below is the way i am packaging right now which created three folders **BOOT_INF, META_INF, ORG**. The reason of asking this is because runnable jar is not able to locate a folder which is inside META-INF.

```
<build>
    <finalName>XYZ</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>XYZ</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>XYZ</exclude>
                                <exclude>XYZ</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>XYZ</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <wait>1000</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>250</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>XYZ</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tarLongFileMode>XYZ</tarLongFileMode>
                    <tarLongFileMode>XYZ</tarLongFileMode>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>XYZ</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>XYZ</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any help which plugin i can use in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue resolved in my case after adding META-INF folder under resources.